# PHP parse block of text for usernames

Tags: php

I want to take a block of text like the following:

```
Hey @max. How are you?
```

And be able to tell if the 'word' `@max` is in it. I say word, because of this situation:

```
Hey @max2. How are you?
```

I don't want to register both `@max` and `@max2` as being present in that block of text, just `@max2`.

EDIT:

I'm trying to identify user mentions in a block of text. So, for example, if I have the users `['max', 'max2', 'maxh']` and I loop through them, I want to only return exact matches. `max` is a substring of `max2` and `maxh`, so when a user mentions `max2`, I only want to detect the user `max2`, and not the user `max`

Some sample code:

```
foreach ($userNames as $userName) {
    if (/* username is present in $text... */) {
        //notify user
    }
}
```

Comment: `/@\w+/` is... all you need, I think? It's difficult to understand your question.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol How's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

You can use `preg_match_all` to return all matches for a given regular expression. You can use `/@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/` to match the following username variations:

```
@max
@max2
@max23_
@max2-
@231
@m2
...
```

Here's a working example:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fNO

**Code**

```
<?php

$input_lines = 'Hey @max2. How are you?';
preg_match_all("/@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/", $input_lines, $output_array);
// Output the results
print_r($output_array);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
( 
  [0] => Array
  (
     [0] => @max2
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think this does the opposite of what I was originally asking, but I wasn't clear. Perhaps now it is more clear? Thank you!

Comment: It's the same exact way, you just need to modify the regular expression to match any form of usernames. I edited the answer to match your inquiry. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your edit made it more clear what was going on. That works for me. Thanks!